# Creating a OpenCV/EmguCV GpuMat from a Cuda device pointer

Tags: opencv, cuda, emgucv

I can create a Mat object in EmguCV from a unmanaged buffer, either pinned in managed memory of created with AllocHGlobal.

How do I create a GpuMat, or similar object, using memory allocated on the device either by device pointer or a Cuda array.

Comment: http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d0/d60/classcv_1_1cuda_1_1GpuMat.html#ab7210166f4bd124855b520b3dde28fb1

Comment: @talonmies, thanks! make this an answer so I can mark bump it!

Comment: Write your own answer. It is perfectly ok to answer your own guest',own questions on [so]

Comment: The link concerns the unmanaged (C++) GpuMat. The question was how to create a managed (EmGu) GpuMat. The managed version (in versions 3.0.x and 3.1.x) does not have a constructor taking an IntPtr. So I do not understand the answer.

Answer (score 1):

talonmies gave me this excellent piece of information! managedCuda gives us an easy way to create ManagedMemory which has both a device pointer and an intptr!!

See [docs/opencv/trunk/....](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39301573/creating-a-opencv-emgucv-gpumat-from-a-cuda-device-pointer?noredirect=1#comment66659962_39301573)

Thanks!